# Mapping the subdivision of an matrix to a vector

Tags: c++, matrix, sudoku

I am trying to map the subdivision of a matrix to an array.
By subdivision of a matrix I mean a box like the 3x3 boxes in a 9x9 sudoku matrix.

To do so I use :

```
grid[x][y] = box[x/3 + (y/3)*3];
```

But it does not work, any sugesstion on a solution and an explanation of why it does not work ?

EDIT:
I know how to map a vector to a matrix.
I want to map a vector to a portion of a square matrix like just like in the sudoku game.

EDIT2:
Bassicaly what I want is to be able to map a box number to a tuple ,
for example with 3x3 boxes and a 9x9 matrix
(0,0) => 1
(0,1) => 1
(8,8) => 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer to Edit2:**

If you want a mapping like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

then your original code is almost want you want (just add 1):

```
for (int y = 0; y < 9; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; ++x) 
    {
        int index = x/3 + (y/3) * 3 + 1;
        printf("%d ", index);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9
```

Comment: weird I tested your code and it works but somehow I was right from the start, thank you I should investigate somewhere else :)